# Where Should I Put Configuration Files?

Tags: windows, linux, configuration

I'm creating a project that I want to be able to distribute across platforms. I'm writing in Java and AWT which already gives me a pretty large range of devices, but I'm mostly interested in Windows and Linux (Debian/Ubuntu).

I'm trying to determine where I should put config files. I have application-wide configuration files and user-specific files. Where are common directories to put these files?

Here's my current setup:

### Windows:

App Config: `%PROGRAMDATA%\MyApp\config\`

User Config: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\MyApp\`

### Other:

App Config: `/opt/MyApp/config`

User Config: `$HOME/.MyApp/`

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: If you're going to use environment variables to construct paths, at least use %LOCALAPPDATA%. There's nothing that guarantees that the path you constructed there from the user profile actually points out the local appdata. If you've got Win32 bindings, prefer [Known Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It looks like in general the problem can be avoided by using something like [platformdirs](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds OK, it's pretty much what most software does. But in Linux, you might want to put the app configuration files in `/etc` (or under a subdirectory, e.g. `/etc/myapp`) as it's more fitting to the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard):

> `/etc` Host-specific system-wide configuration files

Also, you might want to put user configuration in `~/.config/MyApp` rather than `~/.MyApp`. This helps reduce clutter in the user's home directory.

Comment: I especially support the advice about ~/.config/MyApp rather than ~/.MyApp.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert, but in my experience, Linux puts some default (non-editable) config files in `/etc/your-app-here`, whereas user-editable config files these days go in `~/.config/your-app-here` (that is `$HOME/.config/your-app-here`)

[Reference link](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/config-spec)

Comment: files under `/etc/` are of course **editable**, and *are* edited to configure system-wide behaviour; however, you need special permissions (e.g. by being `root`) to make these changes.